# pop up does not open when using select and option in react.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to have create a pop up using select and option in react. But the pop up does not open. Data seems be to correctly logging. Here is my code

```
var List = React.createClass({

 getList(){
    console.log("get list");
    this.props.store.map(function(item){
            return (<option value={item.value}>
                        {item.label}
                    {console.log(item.label)}
                   </option>);
        });
},

render: function(){
    return(<div>
        <select className="form-group" onChange={this.changeHandler} >
                    {this.getList()}
        </select>       

         </div>);
}

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are not returning any value from getList method.
You should return mapped data from getList():

```
var List = React.createClass({
    getList(){
        console.log("get list");
        return this.props.store.map(function(item){
          return (
            <option value={item.value}>
              {item.label}
              {console.log(item.label)}
            </option>);
          });
    },

    render: function(){
        return(
          <div>
            <select className="form-group" onChange={this.changeHandler} >
              {this.getList()}
            </select>  
          </div>);
    }

});
```

Comment: Thanks, It is the correct answer,  but what does the return inside the map is doing?

Comment: Well, map function return you an array of elements, returned by return statement inside.

Comment: For example of map documentation you can check for example lodash's map description https://lodash.com/docs#map